# Creating a node works on local but not on production

Tags: nodes

I'm using the same version of Drupal 8 on both local and production. I'm trying to create a node using the Drupal 8 core REST api.

My curl looks like:

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "X-CSRF-Token:mytoken" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/hal+json" \
   -H "Authorization:Basic authstring" \
   -d \
'{"_links":{"type":{"href":"https://www.example.com/rest/type/node/page"}}, "title":[{"value":"My first page"}], "type":[{"target_id":"page"}]}' \
 'https://www.example.com/node?_format=hal_json'
```

On my Vagrant environment, it works and the node is created on the Drupal 8 site. However, on the production environment I get the error message:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException:
>   No route found for "GET /node": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST) in
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest()
>   (line 143 of
>   /example/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php).

All the settings between local and production are synced using Configuration Management so should be the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update: I also tried creating a custom rest resource. Again, works fine on my local but I get the same error on the production site. Any ideas how I can debug this.

Comment: Changing hal+json to just json works. Not sure why this is a problem as hal_json is checked as an accepted format